# Maintain State of the view and edit using angular route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am trying to build and application where I'll be having 2 users
1 will be having view right and other one will be having View + Edit right. There are "n" no of feilds in each page so I am thinking to have separate HTML pages for view and edit.
What will be best possible way to achieve angular routing as follows
This should be normal for all users which will be view only
http://localhost:4000/#!/moduleName/someID/generalPage

once user click on edit route should change to
http://localhost:4000/#!/edit/moduleName/someID/generalPage
OR
http://localhost:4000/#!/moduleName/someID/generalPage/edit

something like that. If there is any other way which will be more appropriate please suggest or if there is any plugins available please suggest that will also work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you already know to use the angular routing framework. No additional libraries needed. As for structuring your URLs that's really just personal preference. I like option 2 (having `edit` on the end).

Comment: I am not able to achieve that routing can you please suggest if you have any examples

Comment: I suggest googling for an angular routing tutorial. Copying and pasting my code won't help you.

Comment: okay will try Thanks @jebar8